# Can't use var element in Spring Web Flow definition?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, spring-webflow

I'm trying to declare a variable in my flow following the documentation, using

```
<var name="myVar" class="int" />
```

However, Eclipse highlights the `var` as an error, and I get a parser exception when running the flow (either from within Eclipse or from a standalone jar):

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'var'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":input, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":on-start, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":action-state, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":view-state, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":decision-state, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":subflow-state, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":end-state, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":global-transitions, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":on-end, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":output, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":exception-handler, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":bean-import}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1796)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:113)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.XmlFlowModelBuilder.init(XmlFlowModelBuilder.java:112)
```

I'm using the latest XSD:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">
```

and I've verified that the 2.4 XSD both on the Spring server and in the jar do in fact contain the definition for the `var` element, right along with `input`, `on-start`, and the other working elements.

Any idea what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the *var* element within some action-state or something. *var* element is used to set values when the flow is started.
If you want to set some value within a state use *set* element.
At times, we get the values from the caller flow which we access in the current flow using *input* element.

var element can be used at the beginning of the flow as shown below:

```
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

    <var name="someVarName" class="someClassName"/>

    <action-state id="myActionState">
        <set name="someName" value="123"/>
        <evaluate expression="myAction.methodInMyAction()"/>
        <transition on="..." to="..." />
    </action-state>
    ...
    </flow>
```

Comment: No, it's directly under the root element.

Comment: @chrylis What version of SWF are you using?

Comment: 2.4.1, the latest. The bizarre part is that I manually inspected the XSD, and the proper declaration is there. I have no idea why the parser won't take it.

Answer (score 0):

I think var declaration only support class and not native type. So variable should be declare as

```
<var name="myVar" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```